# Is there a way to set a cookie in @before.request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want my application to be able to detect the user's language to serve the corresponding page to them. My idea was to use @before.request to read the `Accepted-Languages` header, match it against the app's supported languages, and set a cookie if needed, but it seems that the last step is not achievable.
Here is the code for that:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request_callback():
    if request.cookies.get('lang'):
        pass
    else:
        lang = request.accept_languages.best_match(supported_languages)
        print(lang)
        #I would like to set the cookie here
```

I thought about setting the cookie in the response object directly in the decorator (`resp.set_cookie()`) and thus reformatted all the returns in my app to look like this

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    resp = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
    return resp
```

to maybe be able to fetch the cookie and attach it to this response, but since the response is created afterwards in the endpoitn function, i have no idea how to do that either.

I also thought about creating the response directly in the decorator, but since i need the return condition, i don't know if thats possible

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use a cookie when you don't need to. As you noted, you can only set cookies on the response. You [send the browser cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) in the response and then it re-sends them to you in any subsequent request. But it's already sending you the `Accept-Language`. So there's no point in setting a cookie on the request. It's already arrived, and already contains what you need.

Instead of getting hung up on setting cookies, just consult the request at the point that you're generating the response to ensure that the served content is in the appropriate language.

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    lang = request.accept_languages.best_match(supported_languages)
    return render_template(f'{lang}/index.html')
```